# Theory containing all sentences of the language

Tags: logic

According to Enderton, the theory which consists of all sentences of the language is the only unsatisfiable theory. Why is this true? In particular, this implies that there exists at most one sentence which cannot be satisfied with all the others, and I don't understand why that must be the case.

Comment: How does it imply "that there exists at most one sentence which cannot be satisfied with all the others"?

Comment: "there exists at most one sentence which cannot be satisfied with all the others" - I don't understand the meaning of this sentence. What does it mean that a sentence satisfies another sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a theory is not just an arbitrary subset of all sentences of a language. Rather, it must be closed under logical implication. Therefore, a theory cannot be all sentences but one: If only one of $p$, $\neg p$, $q$, $\neg q$ is missing, we still have one sentce and its negation; so if e.g. $q$ is missing, we still have $p$ and $\neg p$, from which we get $p\land \neg p$ and then with $(p\land \neg p)\to q$ we resurrect $q$.

Comment: Not every definition of a theory requires it to be closed under implication. Actually, most definitions I have encountered take a theory to be just an arbitrary set of sentences in some language (or sequents, or something like that).

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, Enderton defines a theory to be a set of sentences which is closed under logical entailment. That is, if $T$ is a theory and $T\models \varphi$, then $\varphi\in T$. Note that the statement is not true if a theory is just an arbitrary set of sentences: For any sentence $\varphi$, the theory $\{\varphi\land \lnot \varphi\}$ is unsatisfiable, but this singleton set is not the set of all sentences in the langauge.

Suppose $T$ is unsatisfiable. Then for any sentence $\varphi$, we have that for any model $M\models T$, also $M\models \varphi$ (vacuously: there are no models of $T$). So $T\models \varphi$, and hence $\varphi\in T$, since $T$ is a theory. So $T$ is the set of all sentences in the language.

If instead you define a theory to be deductively closed (if $T$ is a theory and $T\vdash \varphi$, then $\varphi\in T$), then you need to get the completeness theorem involved. The completeness theorem says that $T\vdash \varphi$ if and only if $T\models \varphi$, so you can just use the previous argument and appeal to completeness.